# How to detect if template argument is an std::initializer_list

Tags: c++

In the following example, the last line fails because the conversion operator of `JSON` has to choose between two possibilities:

1. `std::vector<int>::operator=(std::vector<int>&&)`
2. `std::vector<int>::operator=(std::initializer_list<int>)`

How can I constrain `JSON::operator T()` so it ignores the `initializer_list` overload?

```
struct JSON
{
    using StorageType = std::variant<
        int,
        float,
        std::string,
        std::vector<int>,
        std::vector<float>
    >;
    
    StorageType storage;

    template<class T>
    operator T() const {
        return std::get<T>(storage);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const JSON json;
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    numbers = json; // more than one operator '=' matches these operands

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to disable the conversion of `initializer_list`

```
template<class>
constexpr inline bool is_initializer_list = false;
template<class T>
constexpr inline bool is_initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> = true;

struct JSON
{
    // ...
    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!is_initializer_list<T>>* = nullptr>
    operator T() const {
        return std::get<T>(storage);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MTWz6Pco4)

Answer (score 6):

While the question for how to constrain `get` to exclude `std::initializer_list` is legitimate, I think what actually should be checked for is whether `T` is one of the types represented in the `std::variant` of `StorageType`.

You may check if a type is contained in the list of types of a `std::variant` as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename VariantT>
static inline constexpr bool variant_contains_type_v = false;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
static inline constexpr bool variant_contains_type_v<T, std::variant<Ts...>> = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;
```

Your implementation may then be adapted to

```
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<variant_contains_type_v<T, StorageType>>>
    operator T() const {
    return std::get<T>(storage);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Pf3x7bEYd

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to C++20, you might use `requires` instead of SFINAE with `std::enable_if`:

```
// Some filtering traits
// Can even be turned into concept
template <typename>
constexpr inline bool is_initializer_list = false;
template <typename T>
constexpr inline bool is_initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> = true;

struct JSON
{
    // ...
    template <typename T>
    operator T() const requires(!is_initializer_list<T>)
    {
        return std::get<T>(storage);
    }
};
```